# Traduzir tema do Moodle

Tags: moodle

Instalei os seguintes temas no meu Moodle: BCU, Essentials e Klass. Porém estes temas estão em inglês. Acessei alguns arquivos e traduzi o que estava em inglês, mas não deu 100% certo. Algumas coisas ainda estão sem tradução como se vê na seleção de idiomas na imagem abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém sabe aonde eu posso editar o arquivo para que traga todos o site em portugues?

Comment: O Moodle permite traduzir as strings próprias do site, eu gostaria de saber como fazer para traduzir as informações que adicionamos aos campos como conteúdo, seria possível incluir essas strings no arquivo de idioma e suas traduções para outros idiomas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você deve ir em administração do site/idioma/personalização de idiomas, e selecionar o idioma, após a seleção abra o pacote de idiomas e faça o trabalho de "formiguinha" procurando as strings em cada componente a serem traduzidas e insira as traduções correspondentes.

Não se esqueça de limpar o cache dos temas após as modificações.